# How to hide SystemTray

Tags: windows-phone-7, hide, opacity, system-tray

I am having an issue with SystemTray.

My app has Panorama and Pivot screens. So i wish to make SystemTray invisible on both screens.

My code was:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

The headache mostly was because tray reappears after gesture is received like flick or any other actions

I have made the following changes also:

```
shell:SystemTray.Opacity="0"
shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor="Transparent"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
```

It became worse. Tray became visible and with White color in spite of setting it as Transparent.

Regards.

Comment: Do you have a way to reproduce the the system tray being displayed when it's visibility is set to false?

Comment: what do you mean by push received? I have push integrated with my application and i have pivot/panorama controls with system tray disabled and it works smoothly as expected. need more inputs to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting visibilty in the code behind using

```
        SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
```

If it doesn't work, in the constructor of the page or in the OnNavigatedTo function try the following line of code

```
        SystemTray.SetForegroundColor(this, (Color)App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"]);
```

(Color)App.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundColor"] will set the foreground color as backgroud giving it a transparent effect.

**Will only work if you haven't manually added any custom background.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Setting SystemTray.IsVisible = false; does not work, but matching the foreground of the SystemTray to the background of the app is a great trick that works!

Answer (score 0):

try to delete `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"` from the top of you xaml page. Then try it.
If this not works, then use the code behind on the main page loading event like `SystemTray.IsVisible = false;`

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the SystemTray needs to be set this way in the code behind per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.aspx).

```
SystemTray.SetIsVisible(this, false);
```

Alternatively, if you just want to simulate the same "invisible" effect, set the opacity to 0 to hide most of the bar and the foreground color to transparent to hide the time. The one caveat is that the rest of your controls will still know it is there, so you'll need to adjust the top margin of at least the first control on the page up by 32 pixels (ie Margin="0,-32,0,0) in order to finish off producing the exact same effect as setting it to false in the XAML.

```
SystemTray.SetOpacity(this, 0);
SystemTray.SetForegroundColor(this, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```